# I get 'Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread' error, but my code works as expected

Tags: javascript

Here is a piece of my code to ensure if there is a file in the given URL.

if there is the file based on that file URL we will `console.log('We have context for the question');` else  `console.log('No available context');`

The code works as expected but an error occurs in the console:

```js
speak('note');

function contextExist(url) {

    return new Promise((resolve) => {   

        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('HEAD', url, false);
        xhr.send();
        return resolve(xhr.status==200);  

    });

}


// Speak Module
async function speak(type) {
  
    switch (type) {
               
       case 'note':
       let resolved = await contextExist('https://round-arm-authority.000webhostapp.com/Ultimate%20Video%20Hack/videos/vid1.mp4');
      
       if(resolved === true){
         console.log('We have context for the question'); 
    
       } else {
         console.log('No available context'); 
  
       }

       break;
  }

}
```

Every time I got this error in my console:

[image]

since my code works fine I wonder if this is a serious error or not? How can I fix this error?

**UPDATE:**

```js
speak('note');

function contextExist(url) {

    return new Promise((resolve) => {   

        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('HEAD', url, true);

        xhr.onload = function (e) {
        return resolve(xhr.status==200)
        };
        xhr.onerror = function (e) {
         return resolve(xhr.status==200)
      };

        xhr.send();
         
    });

}


// Speak Module
async function speak(type) {
  
    switch (type) {
               
       case 'note':
       let resolved = await contextExist('https://round-arm-authority.000webhostapp.com/Ultimate%20Video%20Hack/videos/vid1.mp4');
      
       if(resolved === true){
         console.log('We have context for the question'); 
    
       } else {
         console.log('No available context'); 
  
       }

       break;
  }

}
```

Comment: Just rewrite this code to send async requests or neglect the warning. The browser is really clear here - synchronous http requests could possibly ruin the performance of your website. And obviously, you open a synchronous request here.

Comment: You can't just replace `false` with `true`, async requests require a callback that is called when the result is available.

Comment: The answer is in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests).

Comment: Do you know what  the difference between synchronous and asynchronous is? You are using promises (good!) and yet make a synchronous XMLHttpRequest, which gives the impression that you don't quite now what promises are good for. But regardless, I assume that a browser that supports `async/await` also supports [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). You should use that instead of `XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: please have a look at my question update... Is that a good solution ... the error has gone

Comment: Sure, that works. You should still look into `fetch` though since it basically is a built-in version of wrapping an XMLHttpRequest into a promise.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open